# submit method of Java concurrent framework

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

New to submit method of Java concurrent framework. Wondering whether the thread got executed when I call submit or when I call get? Researched Oracle official document, but cannot find too much information. Thanks.

I am referring to the sample below,

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html

```
package de.vogella.concurrency.callables;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class CallableFutures {
  private static final int NTHREDS = 10;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS);
    List<Future<Long>> list = new ArrayList<Future<Long>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
      Callable<Long> worker = new MyCallable();
      Future<Long> submit = executor.submit(worker);
      list.add(submit);
    }
    long sum = 0;
    System.out.println(list.size());
    // now retrieve the result
    for (Future<Long> future : list) {
      try {
        sum += future.get();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    executor.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's explained in the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-

Comment: @JBNizet, vote up for the reply, and I read this document. It is not explicitly said whether when task is executed when submit (considering simple case, there are enough number of active threads, than number of tasks to run). My guess from the document is, the task is executed when I submit, but I am not sure, so it is why I come here to ask. Your advice is appreciated.

Comment: If there is a thread available (i.e. the queue is empty), then the task is executed immediately. Otherwise, it's put in the queue until a thread is available.

Comment: task is executed after it is submitted AND there are free working thread to actually execute it. Calling to get() has no effect on executing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, calling submit doesn't execute the task. And calling get doesn't execute the task. The task is processed asynchronously in a thread belonging to the executor's threadpool.

Calling the submit method gives a task to a threadpool. The task is queued up until one of the threads in the pool is free. Then the pool assigns the task to the worker thread, which invokes the code.

When you call Future.get, then either a worker has finished processed your task, a worker is currently processing your task, or the task is still queued up waiting for a worker to become available. If your task is done then the future returns the value returned from the Callable task, otherwise calling the future's get method causes your main thread to block until the task is finished.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, vote up. If there are more active threads than number of tasks, I think the task will get executed when submit (other than get executed when execute `get` method), correct?

Comment: @LinMa: it still gets queued up, it just takes next to no time for a worker to start processing the task. i think it's still helpful to recognize the division of labor involved, which is why i answered that calling submit doesn't (directly) execute the task.

Answer (score 1):

The method `submit()` submits your task to the thread pool while `Future#get()` makes the current thread wait until the task has been executed by one thread of the pool whatever it fails or not.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, vote up. If there are more active threads than number of tasks, I think the task will get executed when submit (other than get executed when execute `get` method), correct?

Comment: it depends on the reject policy of your thread pool, or more precisely the RejectedExecutionHandler used

Comment: in your case, it will throw an exception if all the threads are used and the queue is full

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, vote up. Why exception? In my case, there are more threads than tasks. :)

Comment: if you want to let the current thread execute the task if there is no thread available and the queue is full, you need to use execute instead of submit

Comment: sorry I misunderstood, in this case it will be normally managed by the pool, it is not considered as an issue by the pool

Comment: @LinMa, Re, "If ... [then] I think the task will get executed when submit..."  Don't think that way.  That's a concrete way of thinking.  You should be thinking about the _abstraction_.  An abstract `ExecutorService` will perform the task that you submit _as soon as it is able_, and the `get()` method will wait (if needed) for the task to finish and then return its value.  The abstraction doesn't make any more promises than that, and if those promises aren't sufficient to meet your needs, then you are using the wrong abstraction.